# Atualizar array posições especificas usando mongodb com ou sem Mongoose!

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Tenho a seguinte situação!

```
const meuModel = new mongoose.Schema({

  nome: { type: String, required: [true, 'Nome'] },
  
  links:{type : Array,},
})
```

Links é um array de objetos!

links [{url:link, clicks:0},{url:link1, clicks:0},{url:link2, clicks:0}]

Eu preciso fazer update especifico. Sem nunca mudar os clicks, nem mexer neles!

```
links [{url:link, clicks:4},{url:novoLink, clicks:0},{url:link2, clicks:5},{url:novoLink2, clicks:0}]
```

eu quero permitir o usuário modificar os Links como quiser. Mas os clicks sempre serão via sistema.

Meu problema esta me salvar isso no mongo!

```
teste = await MeuModel.findOneAndUpdate({
          _id
        },{$inc: {
          "links.0.url":'novolink', 
          "links.1.url": 'linkantigo', 
          "links.2.url": 'novo link se for novo',   
      }}
```

Isso não funciona!
Pois quer mudar uma posição, só quando viver do front algo novo!
Se o usuário mudou 3 links, eles devem ser salvos!

"$set" não aceita que eu percorra o array para modificar somente onde for preciso!
"$set" só permite mudança de 1 posição especifica

```
await meuModel.findOneAndUpdate({
          _id
        },{ 
          "$set": {[`links.$[outer].url`]: 'novoLink'} 
        },
        { 
          "arrayFilters": [{ "outer.url":'antigoLink'}]
        })
```

$set com arrayFilters só aceita uma condição para muitos ou apenas 1.

Quero poder mandar salvar o array todo de uma vez, com as modificações apenas dos links, se ela existirem!

Answer (score -1):

Consegui usando
o comando save()

Minha lógica:
Dados vem do front modificados ou não!
chamo o meu model pelo ID.

```
const links = await meuModel.findOne({
    _id
   })

   links.links.forEach((v,i) =>{
  
 
   if(v.url !== front.links[i]?.url){
     

   links.links[i].url = front.links[i]?.url
  
   }

 })
 Links.markModified('links')
 const save =  await links.save()
```

uso forEach para comparar os dados do front com os do back

forEach
compara cada posição do array do front com cada posição do array que veio do
banco

se algum link esta diferente do antigo, o novo é adicionado na mesma posição!

```
links.links[Posicao].url = dado_do_front na mesma posição
```

Faço isso em todas as posições
aviso ao mongo que mudei o array

```
Links.markModified('links')

const save =  await links.save()
```

Esta lógica funciona perfeitamente! Os links são mudados e os clicks nunca mexidos

Mas não sei se é a melhor lógica!